# Dell servers, OpenStack and Autopilot Beta ... can they work together?

Tags: dell, juju, landscape, openstack-autopilot, ceph

I am trying to bring up OpenStack using the Autopilot beta release. I am using all iron (physical servers). All Dell PowerEdge servers, to be specific, I am using:

- 2 x r310 servers
- 3 x r415 servers
- 2 x r610 servers
- 1 x r815 server

I am starting with Ubuntu 14.04.2 running on one of the r310 servers as my MAAS.

My challenge is with the way that Dell reports disk to the "lshw" command. As an example, one of the r415 servers has 4 physical drives attached to a "SAS1068E" controller. They are defined as two RAID0 arrays in the controller (totaling 4TB and 1.2TB each). But the "discovered details" reports the following in the detailed results of the "lshw":

- /dev/sdc - size 3999688294400
- /dev/sdd - size 1199101181952
- /dev/sda - size not listed
- /dev/sdb - size not listed
- /dev/sde - size 1476395008

and the CEPH deployment fails on this node with a 'hook failed: "mon-relation-changed"' message.

The details from the unit-cep-0.log are:

```
2015-04-21 19:21:24 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 ceph-mon-all start/running
2015-04-21 19:21:42 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 Problem opening /dev/sda for reading! Error is 123.
Reading package lists... 87%t.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 
Reading package lists... 98%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       eph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 
Reading state information... Doneh/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/usr/sbin/ceph-disk", line 2768, in <module>
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     main()
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/usr/sbin/ceph-disk", line 2746, in main
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     args.func(args)
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/usr/sbin/ceph-disk", line 1390, in main_prepare
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     zap(args.data)
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/usr/sbin/ceph-disk", line 1013, in zap
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     with file(dev, 'wb') as dev_file:
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 IOError: [Errno 123] No medium found: '/dev/sda'
2015-04-21 19:21:45 ERROR unit.ceph/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 mon:9: Unable to initialize device: /dev/sda
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-0/charm/hooks/mon-relation-changed", line 312, in <module>
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     hooks.execute(sys.argv)
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-0/charm/hooks/charmhelpers/core/hookenv.py", line 508, in execute
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     self._hooks[hook_name]()
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-0/charm/hooks/mon-relation-changed", line 196, in mon_relation
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     reformat_osd(), config('ignore-device-errors'))
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-0/charm/hooks/ceph.py", line 327, in osdize
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     osdize_dev(dev, osd_format, osd_journal, reformat_osd, ignore_errors)
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-0/charm/hooks/ceph.py", line 375, in osdize_dev
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40     raise e
2015-04-21 19:21:45 INFO unit.ceph/0.mon-relation-changed logger.go:40 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ceph-disk-prepare', '--fs-type', u'xfs', '--zap-disk', u'/dev/sda']' 
returned non-zero exit status 1
2015-04-21 19:21:45 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:86 hook "mon-relation-changed" failed: exit status 1
```

It seems that I have been able to deploy all except Ceph, without issue. Am I missing something? Is there a way to tell juju to ignore or not use /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, and /dev/sde?

Comment: Can you, as an experiment, try getting rid of the raid view, and just having disks on the system?  Does the situation improve?

Comment: I did try it without the RAID ... the results were essentially the same. The CD/DVD drive is still being reported as a regular drive with no size, same with the USB controller. The NV-RAM is still being reported as a regular drive with size but as read-only and ceph trips over one or more of them during the install phase.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. (Update: confirmed by the submitter).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/ceph/+bug/1420094

Comment: I appreciate the pointer. This appears to be a duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/ceph/+bug/1420094 (reported in February). I seems that I am the 3rd person to encounter this situation. That surprised me ... I thought more people were using Dell servers....

Comment: @PatE Would you mind pasting the output of: `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdX` for each drive?  Maybe even attaching to that bug instead of here?